# Как исправить "sql: unknown driver "sqlite3" (forgotten import?)" при кросс-компиляции с Windows на Linux?

Tags: golang, кросс-компиляция

Добрый день! Ошибка при запуске скомпилированного из под Windows файла на linux машине:

```
sql: unknown driver "sqlite3" (forgotten import?)
```

На Windows все работает нормально

Пробовал драйвер github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 и github.com/mxk/go-sqlite

Компиляция:

```
set GOOS=linux 
go build entry.go
```

Код: http://pastebin.com/8iqvhp1n
Импорт библиотеки: `_ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"`

Из-за чего это происходит и как это можно решить?

Go 1.7.4, Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос минимальный необходимый пример  (информацию по ссылке могут удалить или изменить).

Comment: У вас точно компиляция проходит успешно? sqlite3 написан на си, следовательно кросскомпилироваться без кросскомпилятора си не должен.

Comment: В консоли при компиляции ошибок нет. "кросскомпилятора си", можно поподробнее?

Comment: Для того, чтобы из под одной операционной системы компилировать код для другой, нужен кросскомпилятор. В го обычный компилятор является кросскомпилятором по умолчанию, но в си это бывает не так. Попробуйте сделать `go build` с `GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=1`.

Comment: # runtime/cgo
C:\Users\eee\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build336598898\runtime\cgo\_obj\_cgo_main.c:1:0: error: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent) [-Werror]
 
int main() { return 0; }
 
^

cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors

(http://pastebin.com/8EAsRD9i)

Comment: @Festelo Вот теперь вы получаете ошибки компилятора си (cc1.exe). Ищите информацию о кросскомпиляции си с винды на линукс. Насчёт того, как это применить в отношении го вот [хорошая статья](https://medium.com/@rakyll/go-1-5-cross-compilation-488092ba44ec#.lgjf1zf67).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в то что при получении пакета (или сборки) `go get -u github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3` под Windows происходит сборка драйвера sqlite для текущей платформы, необходимо выполнить сборку самого драйвера для linux:

```
set GOOS=linux 
go build -v github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
```

После этого уже собирать свое приложение

[Кросс компиляция Go в Windows (github golang wiki)](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsCrossCompiling)